# How to use SVM to do time series prediction?

Tags: time-series, svm

I want to know how to use SVM to do time series prediction? what the differences of input vecvtor X of our model between time-series prediction and standard kernelized regression problem？

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental difference in case of time-series prediction against general regression problem (not only for SVM) is the dependence of response on more than one cases.

So, for example if the input vector with `N` cases is **X<sub>1</sub>...X<sub>N</sub>**, then for predicting some case number `n`, all the input-response data from **X<sub>1</sub>** through **X<sub>n-1</sub>** can be used (and are supposed to effect its outcome).

Generally, a fixed number of cases immediately preceding the case to be predicted are used. One way to do time-series prediction with **SVM** is to transform your input variable **X** to include features derived from the desired number of preceding cases.

Here is a code example by *[Quantum Financer](https://quantumfinancier.wordpress.com/2010/06/26/support-vector-machine-rsi-system/)*.